# Print "cout" before cin?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, iostream

I've got a small problem and I'm not sure if there's a possible way around this with iostream code, but I thought it's worth asking anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string cmd;

int main() {

cout << "-------------" << endl;
cout << "command: ";
cin >> cmd;
cout << "-------------" << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Is it anyway possible to print the 3rd `cout` line before the user has typed into the `cmd` variable? That way, the text field will be wrapped with the `"-"` above and below, looking like this:

```
-------------
command: <user would type here>
-------------
```

If this is not possible, could you please point me into the direction of some possible libraries that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: yes you can, but you've got to ask yourself: Is is worth it?

Comment: You would need some kind of cursor control library.  Some command lines  let you move the cursor around with escape sequences.  It really depends on your environment.

Comment: Hi @bolov, I'm making a text based adventure game, and the UI will consist of this being wrapped around the text field, so if I can figure out how to do it simply in this example, I can further implement it when I build my UI

Comment: Have you heard of [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.org/)?

Comment: Hi @Eljay, I have, I just struggled to get to grips with it all, as I couldn't find solid documentation on all functions etc. Is this what you would recommend? If so I'll fully commit and look into this.

Comment: It is one option that you can consider.  There are also direct WinAPI calls you could consider.  It really depends on what you need.

Comment: @Eljay for a simple task just like this for example, what would you recommend?

Comment: I'd use PDCurses (on Windows) or the very similar NCurses (on Unix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you could try to use [SetConsoleCursorPosition function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to set the cursor position in the specified console screen buffer.

This code uses SetConsoleCursorPosition() to move the current output location to row 1, column 9:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

string cmd;

int main()
{


    cout << "-------------\n" << "command:  \n" << "-------------" << endl;


    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hConsole)
    {
        COORD pos = {9, 1 };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
        cin >> cmd;
    }


    system("pause");

}
```

[image]

Comment: This works exactly how I want it to, thank you! I should be able to build the rest of my UI with manipulation of the cursor position now! I just have 2 questions, what is "hConsole" getting? (Some reference of the console maybe?) and what is the if statement actually checking?

Comment: hConsole: A handle to the console screen buffer. You could specify a security descriptor for the console screen buffer when calling the [CreateConsoleScreenBuffer function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer).
If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new console screen buffer.If the function fails, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.The if statement is to ensure that the handle of the console screen buffer has [GENERIC_READ access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-buffer-security-and-access-rights).

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard way of achieving this in C++.

Different terminals have their own capabilities and different systems have their own API's for interacting with the terminal.

The output of the bottom line must certainly be performed first before waiting for the input, but it may be possible to move the output "cursor" to some other location than the bottom of the screen. You may find details in the documentation of the system that you intend to target.